# App android for web

Tags: android, web-services, webview

I have a website and want to make an app on android to collect some information from that page. Not that I can use. I have seen in relation to this matter or the use of web services or webview. Someone can guide me to see that I have to use on android. Thank you. Greetings.

Comment: use webservices of php or .net according to your website..

Comment: Use joomla with worpress

Comment: yes...its depend on you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to [scrape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) data from a webpage in an Android app.

You should download the webpage using [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html), and then parse the resulting HTML.

It's quite hard to help you parse the HTML without knowing more.

Comment: ok. thanks for the help. So already where I can start.